# Finder Search attribute "Tags"

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, metadata, finder-tag

It looks like the search attribute "Tags" is no longer available in the Mountain Lion Finder. I used this to quickly find Open Meta Taggged files on my Mac by means of a Smart Folder. Is there an alternative way?

mdfind still recognizes tags > "mdfind tag:tagname" works fine. Obviously the same holds for Spotlight "tag:tagname" works fine.

Comment: Do you mean Mountain Lion **Finder or Spotlight**?

Comment: Mountain Lion Finder - when you start a search query you can select "other" and you could select "tags". Spotlight (like mdfind) still works find since you can still find tag:tagname in Spotlight.